Page keeps scrolling up on every single character typed in iPhone for Persian language
For every single character typed in the iPhone and Android in RTL keyboards, the entire page keeps scrolling upwards
Screen recording
I tested it with the English language and nothing was out of the ordinary. For the first word of a line, it does not scroll. But after one space, it keeps scrolling upwards for each character.
